# Why does debian:package-bin throw "packageDescription in Debian cannot be empty" when build.sbt has the setting?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I want to create an Debian package with my code written in Scala with sbt and sbt-native-package.

But when I try to execute `debian:package-bin` in sbt console, I receive this error:

```
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last debian:debianControlFile for the full output.
[error] (debian:debianControlFile) packageDescription in Debian cannot be empty. Use
[error]                  packageDescription in Debian := "My package Description"
```

This is strange, because in my `build.sbt` I have the `packageDescription` setting as follows:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager._
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.Keys._
import NativePackagerKeys._
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.ServerLoader.{SystemV, Upstart}

serverLoading in Debian := SystemV

name := "testApp"

version := "1.0"

organization := "com.testApp"

scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

maintainer in Debian := "gdc <aaa@aaa.com>"

packageSummary in Debian := "testApp"

packageDescription in Debian := "testApp"

packageArchetype.java_server

exportJars := true
```

I did tests using `packageDescription := "testApp"` or `packageDescription in Linux := "testApp"` but neither worked.

Comment: Could you execute `sbt 'show debian:packageDescription'` from the command line or just execute `sbt` and then `show debian:packageDescription`, and paste the output to the question? I doubt the file `build.sbt` above is part of your build definition.

Comment: Thank you Jacek, the problem was that packageArchetype.java_server overwriting my data. After with show debian:packageDescription returns empty and now returns the correct value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the line

```
packageArchetype.java_server
```

to be just after the imports, so it will not override the settings.

#### build.sbt

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager._
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.Keys._
import NativePackagerKeys._
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.ServerLoader.{SystemV, Upstart}

packageArchetype.java_server

serverLoading in Debian := SystemV

name := "testApp"

version := "1.0"

organization := "com.testApp"

scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

maintainer in Debian := "gdc <aaa@aaa.com>"

packageSummary in Debian := "testApp"

packageDescription in Debian := "testApp"

exportJars := true
```

Comment: Thank you, @lpiepiora, this was the mistake

Comment: For those still struggling, when using the interactive mode in sbt or activator, you must `reload` the project definition each time build.sbt is modified.